# Trying to get a return code from a JDBC query

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have been given a stored procedure by my boss that is supposed to return a code that indicates whether it was successful or had problems. In order to access this procedure and get the return code, I am using the following code:

```
  SQLServerDataSource src = makeConnection();

  CallableStatement statement = null;
  ResultSet resultSet = null;

  try(Connection conn = src.getConnection())
  {
     statement = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call uspGetBillOfMaterials(?,?) }");

     statement.registerOutParameter(1,Types.INTEGER);
     statement.setInt("StartProductID",733);
     statement.setString("CheckDate","2018-02-18 00:00:00.000");

     resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

     if(resultSet != null)
     {
        System.out.println("Query was successful. Code: "+resultSet.getInt(1));
     }
  }
  catch (Throwable t)
  {
     t.printStackTrace();
  }
```

It should be noted that I am using JDBC with Microsoft SQL Server. I am using the Microsoft JDBC driver for SQL Server.

Unfortunately, when I execute this code, I get the following exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetHasCurrentRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:534)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getterGetColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:2006)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2037)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2023)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(SQLServerResultSet.java:2297) 
                                   ...
                       --- The rest removed for brevity---
```

I believe my code is correct for getting a return value. Am I missing something?

Or is the stored procedure written incorrectly? The stored procedure is provided below:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetBillOfMaterials] @StartProductID [int]
    ,@CheckDate [datetime]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnCode INT = 0
        ,@logrowcount VARCHAR(36)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Use recursive query to generate a multi-level Bill of Material (i.e. all level 1 
    -- components of a level 0 assembly, all level 2 components of a level 1 assembly)
    -- The CheckDate eliminates any components that are no longer used in the product on this date.
    WITH [BOM_cte] (
        [ProductAssemblyID]
        ,[ComponentID]
        ,[ComponentDesc]
        ,[PerAssemblyQty]
        ,[StandardCost]
        ,[ListPrice]
        ,[BOMLevel]
        ,[RecursionLevel]
        ) -- CTE name and columns
    AS (
            SELECT b.[ProductAssemblyID]
            ,b.[ComponentID]
            ,p.[Name]
            ,b.[PerAssemblyQty]
            ,p.[StandardCost]
            ,p.[ListPrice]
            ,b.[BOMLevel]
            ,0 -- Get the initial list of components for the bike assembly
        FROM [Production].[BillOfMaterials] b
        INNER JOIN [Production].[Product] p ON b.[ComponentID] = p.[ProductID]
        WHERE b.[ProductAssemblyID] = @StartProductID
            AND @CheckDate >= b.[StartDate]
            AND @CheckDate <= ISNULL(b.[EndDate], @CheckDate)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT b.[ProductAssemblyID]
            ,b.[ComponentID]
            ,p.[Name]
            ,b.[PerAssemblyQty]
            ,p.[StandardCost]
            ,p.[ListPrice]
            ,b.[BOMLevel]
            ,[RecursionLevel] + 1 -- Join recursive member to anchor
        FROM [BOM_cte] cte
        INNER JOIN [Production].[BillOfMaterials] b ON b.[ProductAssemblyID] = cte.[ComponentID]
        INNER JOIN [Production].[Product] p ON b.[ComponentID] = p.[ProductID]
        WHERE @CheckDate >= b.[StartDate]
            AND @CheckDate <= ISNULL(b.[EndDate], @CheckDate)
        )
    -- Outer select from the CTE
    SELECT b.[ProductAssemblyID]
        ,b.[ComponentID]
        ,b.[ComponentDesc]
        ,SUM(b.[PerAssemblyQty]) AS [TotalQuantity]
        ,b.[StandardCost]
        ,b.[ListPrice]
        ,b.[BOMLevel]
        ,b.[RecursionLevel]
    FROM [BOM_cte] b
    GROUP BY b.[ComponentID]
        ,b.[ComponentDesc]
        ,b.[ProductAssemblyID]
        ,b.[BOMLevel]
        ,b.[RecursionLevel]
        ,b.[StandardCost]
        ,b.[ListPrice]
    ORDER BY b.[BOMLevel]
        ,b.[ProductAssemblyID]
        ,b.[ComponentID]
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25)
END;

SET @logrowcount = CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), @@ROWCOUNT)

IF @logrowcount = '0'
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnCode = 999
 END

RETURN @ReturnCode
```

Someone please advise. How do I get this to work, and return the return code?

EDIT: The last question I asked in my comment is *not* a duplicate. My question was not properly formed.

I am not asking a general question about how to get a result set. I am askig about how to get my result set *after I have read the return code from the statement*.

The problem is that my boss' Stored Procedure is returning a code that tells, among other things, whether or not there is data in the result set that I need to acquire. Unfortunately, if I read the code using statement.getInt(), the ResultSet object gets "closed" and after getting a return code that says there is data I the ResultSet's getXXX() functions generate an exeption because of the closing of the ResultSet. What I am actually trying to ask is whether or not there is a way of getting the return code from a CallableStatement without closing the ResultSet -- or conversely, if there is a way to reopen the ResultSet once I have grabbed the return code. The answer referred to does not address this question.

My question also implies an additional concern: have I found a bug in the CallableStatement API? That question certainly is not answered anywhere here...

Comment: (Disclaimer: I've never used `CallableStatement`.) I believe you should be using `CallableStatement.getInt` rather that through a `ResultSet`. Also I suspect you need to name parameters in the query to be able to refer to them by name, rather than it being done by metadata. Probably needs proprietary SQL `CALL` statements rather than the `{call}` syntax. But as I say, I've never used `CallableStatement`. Edit: Oh but `ResultSet` needs `next` on it called before the first row is read.

Comment: So, did you try changing `if(resultSet != null) { System.out.println("Query was successful. Code: "+resultSet.getInt(1)); }` to `if(resultSet.next()) { System.out.println("Query was successful. Code: "+resultSet.getInt(1)); }` as was suggested?

Comment: Greetings, Tom: Changing from resultset to statement worked, but there is another problem: what if I am supposed to get a result set? I have tried to read the result set after checking the code, only to get an exception saying that the result set was "closed"! How do I get the data in a resultset before it gets closed?

Comment: It's not a bug in `CallableStatement`, it's a "feature" of the way the TDS protocol works. If a stored procedure returns both a result set *and* a return value (or OUTPUT parameters) then the result set is sent back first. Therefore, the client needs to process the result set before it can retrieve the return value. However, in your case the return value only indicates that the result set is empty (@@ROWCOUNT was zero) and you can test for an empty result set using `.next()` so you don't really need the return code anyway.